# android mediaplayer force error for testing

Tags: android, testing, media-player

I have a very simple implementation of MediaPlayer which works fine. For testing purposes, how can I force the code to throw an error? OnErrorListener must be invoked to test failure handling. TIA.

```
    try {
        player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
            }
        });

        player.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                /* handling code */

                /* *********************** */
                /* WANT THIS EVENT TO OCCUR BY FORCE */
                /* *********************** */


            }
        });
        player.prepareAsync();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this by 
pushing media player into invalid state..

for valid and invalid state of media payer look at this.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#Valid_and_Invalid_States

Comment: I knew about this. I can push the MediaPlayer object into an invalid state by calling some given function to force call to onErrorListener. But I was looking for a more formal way by which onErrorListener can be forcefully invoked to simulate an error to test error handling code. Thanks for your input anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If method is void which you mocked then use

```
Mockito.doThrow(Exception::class.java).`when`(intanceOfClass.methodName)
```

For Example:
`` Mockito.doThrow(java.lang.IllegalStateException::class.java).`when`(mediaPlayer.reset()) ``

If method is notVoid then use

```
Mockito.`when`(mediaPlayer.isPlaying).thenThrow(java.lang.IllegalStateException::class.java)
```